# Cannot run roscore with latest Ubuntu 12.04 Packages

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, packages, rospkg, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just ran an update on my system (sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get upgrade) which included a whole bunch of updated ROS packages. Upon rebooting my system I am now unable to run anything ROS related. Even running roscore presents the same error:

```
rctoris@MAGLEV:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/rctoris/.ros/log/713123b6-c157-11e1-bd8b-782bcbad8931/roslaunch-MAGLEV-3057.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosversion", line 76, in <module>
    version = rosstack.get_stack_version(stack_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 359, in get_stack_version
    return get_stack_version_by_dir(self.get_path(stack))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 412, in get_stack_version_by_dir
    m = parse_manifest_file(stack_dir, STACK_FILE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 343, in parse_manifest_file
    return parse_manifest(manifest_name, f.read(), filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 404, in parse_manifest
    m.author = _check('author')(p, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 67, in check
    raise InvalidManifest("Invalid manifest file [%s]: must have a single '%s' element"%(filename, name))
rospkg.manifest.InvalidManifest: Invalid manifest file [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.xml]: must have a single 'author' element
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
```

According to [this bug report](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3982), it appears as if there was an update to allow for multiple author tags. Is it possible part of this update did not make it into the debian packages? I am running the Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit Fuerte packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37500/cannot-run-roscore-with-latest-ubuntu-12.04-packages/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sort of duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/37397/update-fuerte-to-1810-breaks-rospkg/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2